# How rxjs last() works?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have to make next sequential HTTP requests to server:

- begin transaction
- create object 1
- create object 2,
- create object N
- commit;

Objects are stored in array. For this, I created next sample rxjs code:

```
import { from, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, last, finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const ids: string[] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];

const obs$: Observable<string> = from(ids)
  .pipe(
    finalize((): void => {
      console.log('finalize');
    }),
    tap((item: string): void => {
       console.log(`tap: ${item}`);
    })
  );

from('1') // replaced by beginTransaction() observable
  .pipe(
     concatMap((): Observable<string> => {
       return obs$;
     }),
     // emit the last value emitted from source on completion
     last(),
     concatMap((): Observable<void> => {
        console.log('commit');
        return of(undefined)
      })
   )
   .subscribe((): void => {
     console.log('subscribe');
   });
```

I'm wondering how `last()` works? Does it wait until inner observable (in my case `obs$` completes)? I'm looking for detailed information here (will look into the source code, but this will take me some time I suppose).

Output:

```
tap: 1
tap: 2
tap: 3
tap: 4
tap: 5
tap: 6
tap: 7
finalize
commit
subscribe
complete
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last

Comment: `last()` waits until its source Observable completes so in your case it's the Observable merged into the chain using `concatMap()`. Then `concatMap()` emits `complete` notification only when its source completes. So basically yes, `last()` will emit when `obs$` completes.

Comment: `last` will keep track of the most recent value emitted from the source that meets its predicate (the default predicate is `true` for all values). It emits nothing until the source completes. Once the source completes, if it has a value that matched its predicate, `last` emits that value and then completes as well. If you unsubscribe to `last`, it unsubscribes to the source and nothing is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

@martin and @Mrk Sef are correct. Looking at the source code -https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/last.ts:

```
export function last<T, D>(
  predicate?: ((value: T, index: number, source: Observable<T>) => boolean) | null,
  defaultValue?: D
): OperatorFunction<T, T | D> {
  const hasDefaultValue = arguments.length >= 2;
  return (source: Observable<T>) =>
    source.pipe(
      predicate ? filter((v, i) => predicate(v, i, source)) : identity,
      takeLast(1),
      hasDefaultValue ? defaultIfEmpty(defaultValue!) : throwIfEmpty(() => new EmptyError())
    );
}
```

last() waits until its source Observable completes. To summarize last() === takeLast(1)